# What we want that the Ask question modal say to first question askers?

Tags: feature-request, ask-question-modal

Below is the current text from the Ask Question modal shown to people asking their first question:

[image: Ask question first question modal]

> ## Asking a good question
>
> You’re ready to ask your first question and the community is here to help! To get you the best answers, we’ve provided some guidance:
>
> Before you post, search the site to make sure your question hasn’t been answered.
>
> 1. Summarize the problem
> 2. Provide details and any research
> 3. When appropriate, describe what you’ve tried

What do we want to say to first-time askers, considering that most new users click the *Ask Question button* without reading the **tour** or anything else about the *GenAI Stack Exchange community*?

Answer (score -2):

I find the "optimism" shown in the opening statement of the *Ask question page* "overwhelming", just to call it in some way constructively:

> You’re ready to ask your first question and the community is here to help! To get you the best answers, we’ve provided some guidance:

It should be replaced by a "pesimistic" but kind tone:

> ## Are you sure you are ready to ask your first question?
>
> If you have not yet read the GenAI [tour](https://genai.stackexhange.com/tour) thoroughly, you should do it before asking your first question as **GenAI Stack Exchange** is not as other question and answer forums on the Web.
>
> Please don't take us the wrong way. Be sure there is a community eager to help. Still, they are focused on helping flesh and blood **people** to build a library of **high-quality questions** for every **original** question about **using** *GenAI tools*.

Comment: I downvoted this because I feel like the original one in the question feels more friendly to the users let alone the new ones. It feels heart-warming, welcome, and kind. Whereas, yours make me feel the opposite. Might be too subjective and selfish from me though. Let's see the others' feedback.

Comment: @holydragon I appreciate your feedback. I have probably seen too many questions on [webapps.se]  and other [se] sites that look to blatantly ignore what the [tour] and the Ask Question page say about the corresponding site. Nowadays, I think that it is better to tell upfront what is expected rather than delay the "unfriendly" / "toxic" face of a [se] community as they are perceived once the downvotes and question closing shows up.

Comment: Even though I downvoted this answer because I feel it is unfriendly, I upvoted the question. I agree with you that the Ask Question Model can be improved to state what is expected from the question askers upfront. However, this answer is just not what I would say I like it to be.